# Pandas. Группировка по дням

Tags: python, pandas

Есть **dataframe** c информацией по дням. Данные до **21-11-2020**. Делаю группировку по месяцам => получаем следующий dataframe.

```
    report_dt   val
0   2019-05-31  1.000000
1   2019-05-31  1.000000
2   2019-05-31  1.000000
3   2019-05-31  1.000000
4   2019-05-31  1.000000
... ... ...
40968   2020-11-21  1.473936
40969   2020-11-21  1.224346
40970   2020-11-21  1.154639
40971   2020-11-21  1.288267
40972   2020-11-21  1.305227


df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key="report_dt", freq="M")).sum()
```

Проблема в том, что мне нужно сделать прогноз до конца ноября месяца **ноябрь 2020**.

```
               val
report_dt   
2019-05-31  89.000000
2019-06-30  2604.222554
2019-07-31  2921.488532
2019-08-31  2788.286942
2019-09-30  2715.984941
2019-10-31  2921.700432
2019-11-30  2780.336395
2019-12-31  3046.813108
2020-01-31  2899.813285
2020-02-29  2743.557685
2020-03-31  3094.199008
2020-04-30  2821.939331
2020-05-31  2943.526237
2020-06-30  2976.331705
2020-07-31  3088.703561
2020-08-31  3003.484790
2020-09-30  2945.784510
2020-10-31  3119.134793
2020-11-30  2055.749978
```

Заполнить недостающие данные за ноябрь 2020 года пустыми значениями и затем делать прогноз?

Comment: Что-то я не понял. Зачем чем-то заполнять, вы просто отрезаете этот ноябрь от тренировочных данных и предсказываете его по остальным данным. Но вообще `Time Series` - тема непростая, нужно не допустить утечку данных из будущего в прошлое.

Comment: Ну неужели проще запостить два скриншота, чем данные текстом, как того требуют правила?

Comment: И уточните - вы прямо за месяц что-то предсказываете или по дням? Просто пока непонятно, как эта группировка связана с вашей задачей вообще.

Comment: @CrazyElf Есть дневные данные. Нужно сделать прогноз для ноября 2020 года. Так как данных очень много, то я сгруппировал их по месяцам и хочу сделать прогноз для ноября 2020 года. Но pandas сгруппировал и сделал вид, как будто есть все данные для ноября 2020 года

Comment: @strawdog спасибо, исправил

Comment: @T1bon Прогноз вы хотите на весь ноябрь делать целиком или по отдельным дням? Если целиком, то просто выкидываете этот ноябрь из трейна и всё, какая разница, что там насуммировалось. Какой метод предсказания и по каким фичам собираетесь вообще использовать?

Comment: У вас, кстати, и 2019-05 явно не полный месяц, рекомендую его тоже выкинуть из данных при тренировке.

Comment: @CrazyElf о, спасибо. Хочу использовать модель ARIMA. Для подбора оптимальных параметров использовать Информационный критерий Акаике (AIC)

Comment: Только сначала проверьте на предыдущих месяцах. Выкидываете, например, все месяцы начиная с сентября, предсказываете сентябрь, проверяете результат. Потом с октябрём тоже самое. Если всё норм, тогда уже за ноябрь беритесь. Но в целом можно на ноябрь где-то `2950` вручную предсказать %)